# C++ structure to define how data has to be arranged and accessed

Tags: c++, structure

New to C++, so I will be writing lot of wrong syntax and stating my intent in English

```
enum class FEATURE
{
  F1,
  F2,
  F3,
  F4
};

typedef struct feature_config {
    std::map<FEATURE, std :: vector<int> > f_conf;
} Config;


typedef struct my_key{

         const Config    key_f_config = {
                                    .f_conf = {
                                        {FEATURE::F1,{20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55}},
                                        {FEATURE::F2,{20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,120}},
                                        {FEATURE::F3,{0,25,50,75,100}},
                                        {FEATURE::F4,{10,20}}
                                     }      
                                  };    

     vector<int> key_data;
 } KEY;
```

I want to do something like

```
KEY *k = (KEY *)data_from_binary_file;

vector *f1v = k->key_f_config[FEATURE::f1]
vector *f2v = k->key_f_config[FEATURE::f2]
vector *f3v = k->key_f_config[FEATURE::f3]
vector *f4v = k->key_f_config[FEATURE::f4]

want to implement something like

getData(F1=20,F2=30,F3=0,F4=20)
```

which will allow me to get the indices corresponding to 20,30,0,20 in respective vectors and allow me to jump to
right offset inside key_data vector of the KEY  (assuming I have knowledge of size of each feature's datum and I can calculate the offset to which I have to jump)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: what's the point of those `typedef`s?

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with the shown code.

The code you showed compiles without any problems with gcc 5.3.1:

```
$ cat t.C
#include <map>
#include <vector>

 enum class FEATURE
{
  F1,
  F2,
  F3,
  F4
};

typedef struct feature_config {
    std::map<FEATURE, std :: vector<int> > f_conf;
} Config;


typedef struct my_key{

         const Config    key_f_config = {
                                    .f_conf = {
                                        {FEATURE::F1,{20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55}},
                                        {FEATURE::F2,{20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,120}},
                                        {FEATURE::F3,{0,25,50,75,100}},
                                        {FEATURE::F4,{10,20}}
                                     }      
                                  };    

     std::vector<int> key_data;
 } KEY;
$ g++ -c -g -o t.o -std=c++14 t.C
$
```

Either the problem is somewhere else, in some other part of the code you did not show, or your compiler does not support C++14.

Comment: Ya, the error was due to typo else where in similar code, my mistake, I have edited the question now.